# RaspberryPi 2 and GitLab: "No such middleware to insert before: ActionDispatch::Static"?

Tags: raspbian, software-installation, git

I was trying to install GitLab 7.8 using this installation method:
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md

However, upon running `sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:shell:install[v2.4.3] REDIS_URL=unix:/var/run/redis/redis.sock RAILS_ENV=production` all I get is this error stack:

```
rake aborted!
No such middleware to insert before: ActionDispatch::Static
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:125:in `assert_index'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:101:in `swap'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/configuration.rb:68:in `block in merge_into'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/configuration.rb:67:in `each'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/configuration.rb:67:in `merge_into'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:497:in `app'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:36:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:288:in `initialize!'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `public_send'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `method_missing'
/home/git/gitlab/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:264:in `require_environment!'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:367:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
Tasks: TOP => gitlab:shell:install => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I made a SWAP file with 512 MB but it doesn't work with or without it. I have the Raspberry Pi 2 Model B.

What can I do to install GitLab 7?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue upgrading from 7.7 to 7.8. If you install 7.7 you won't find this issue. However, if you're planning on using the CI server with a team of developers you should know that there is a bug where non-admin users can't view their builds. This appears to have only been fixed as of 7.8.

Comment: UPDATE: someone just pushed a fix to 7.8.0rc4 https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/1115

Comment: I saw that fix and it worked, but now I've got a SEGFAULT with therubyracer.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the official Omnibus image for Raspberry Pi.

1. Install dependencies:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install openssh-server
   sudo apt-get install postfix
   ```
2. Download the Omnibus package and install everything:

   ```
   wget https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/downloads-packages/raspberry-pi/gitlab_7.9.0-omnibus.pi-1_armhf.deb
   sudo dpkg -i gitlab_7.9.0-omnibus.pi-1_armhf.deb
   ```
3. Configure and start GitLab:

   ```
   sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
   ```

Comment: Yeah, that wasn't available at the time.